# How to set the height of the second div take the rest space?

Tags: html, css

I've got two panels in the following code. The first should be a fixed size (or auto), but the second should get the rest of the space available.

So that's the reason that I set `height:100%;` but it's not still working.

```
<html style="height:100%;">
    <body style="height:100%;">
        <div style="background-color:green;">a
        </div>
        <div style="background-color:gray; height:100%;">d
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What am I missing to display the second panel in the rest of the view.

Comment: I see a green and grey panel. whats the issue? http://jsbin.com/epokid/1/edit

Comment: Well, the green panel should be shown in all the rest of space

Comment: Your question and comment are contradictory.

Comment: "in all of the rest of the space"?

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. I mean like in XAML, set the second panel `height='*'`

Comment: In case somebody doesn't get it, the issue is that the grey panel should occupy 100% minus the fixed height value, not the whole 100%.

Answer (score 0):

i personally like to use position:absolute.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<style>  
  html,body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
  }

  #Green {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    height:30px;
    background-color:green;
  }

  #Gray {
    background-color:gray;
    position:absolute;
    top:30px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
  }
</style>
<body>
  <div id="Green">a</div>
  <div id="Gray">d</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This would force the inheritance of the full length of the div respectful of the top 30px.

Comment: Thank for your answers, it works! But I'd prefer to use the relative way because I'm displaying the first div in different height  depending of the position of the device. So I edited the example (first div height is auto)

Comment: then honestly its going to be either really hacky, or you're looking at a javascript solution.